# CSS Behavior for IE gives me Access Denied

Tags: css, internet-explorer, behavior

I am using htc file in IE to do some CSS stuff.
Problem is, I am downloading the CSS to another URL, and I understand the behavior URL must be relative to the document.

the HTC file is located on a different domain.

Can I still use it remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with these .htc files I know you MUST have it on the same domain with your website.

Comment: is there another solution for this?